# Using SMTP with multi curl?

Tags: curl, libcurl

I've written code to send mail via SMTP using easy curl that was working fine, but when I'm trying to do the same with multi curl the pointer given as `CURLOPT_READDATA` has an unexpected value in the call back function. How do I add two easy handles to multicurl and post different mails?

```
struct upload_status {
  const char *readptr;
  long lines_read;
};
```

This is the structure whose pointer I've set to `READDATA`.